# How can I extend a vertical menu to fill up an entire blank column in Semantic UI?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, pug, semantic-ui

I want to extend the menu on the left to have no padding between the top title menu and to extend to 100% of the vertical height of the page (basically so there is just blank white all the way down under the menu options), but I do not want that gutter to apply to the other column on the right (the text).  Is there a way to do this in Semantic UI?  I've searched the documentation but I don't find anything to accommodate my needs.  Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show relevant HTML and CSS code.

Comment: I added the jade and changed the tag from html to jade, hope that's okay.

Comment: Did you have a look on that? http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html#fitted

I guess it's just what you need

Comment: @FrancescoE. this will change the padding of the menu items themselves, but not between the menu and the top title bar.  It also does not solve the problem of the 100% vertical height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the same, but ended up by doing it myself.

https://jsfiddle.net/cbaconnier/q07vvfp3/2/

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  @media only screen and (min-width: 770px) {
    .menu-wrapper {
      position: relative; 
      margin-bottom: 14px; /* default semantic ui margin */
    }
    .vertical-menu {
      height: 100%; 
      position: absolute; 
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="ui basic segment">
    <div class="ui stackable grid">

        <div class="four wide column menu-wrapper">

            <div class="ui fluid vertical menu vertical-menu">
                <a class="active item"> Home </a>
                <a class="item"> Messages </a>
                <a class="item"> Friends </a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="twelve wide column">
             <div class="ui basic segment">
                    <h1 class="ui header">title</h1>
                </div>
                 <div class="ui basic segment">
                    <h1 class="ui header">title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ui basic segment">
                    <h1 class="ui header">title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ui basic segment">
                    <h1 class="ui header">title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ui basic segment">
                    <h1 class="ui header">title</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="ui basic segment">
                    <h1 class="ui header">title</h1>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the height reduces with the content of the second div. I am not sure if this is the right solution.

Comment: @hadaytullah At the time of my answer, the solution worked as attended for my needs. If it's not your, In the `.menu-wrapper` class you can still, for example, add `height: 100vh;` to have a menu who's taking 100% of your height screen.